# PHP MySQL populating values from database

Tags: php, mysql

lets say i retrieve all of the values where their position belongs to top8.I populate them out in a table and instead of displaying different kinds of values , it displays 3 tables with 3 different values, how is this so? any help so that different values belonging to certain values will all be displayed out? i only need one table with 3 different values.

```
<?
        $facebookID = "top8";
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("schoutweet") or ie(mysql_error());

        $data= mysql_query("SELECT schInitial FROM matchTable WHERE position='".$facebookID."'")
        or die(mysql_error());

        while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($data))
        {

        ?>
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tbl_bracket">
                <tr>
                    <td class="brack_under cell_1"><a href="www.facebook.com"/>team 1.1><?= $row['schInitial']?><a/></td>
                    <td class="cell_2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="cell_3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="cell_4">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="cell_5">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="cell_6">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="brack_under_right_up">team 1.2><?= $row['schInitial']?></</td>
                    <td class="brack_right"><!--1.2.1--></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="brack_right"><!--2.1--></td>
                    <td class="brack_under"><!--3.1--></td>
                    <td><!--here?--></td>
                    <td><!--there?--></td>
                    <td><!--everywhere?--></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </center>
<?
}
?>


</body>
```

Comment: `while` is a loop language construct. You create an loop of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Because your writing the `table` tag **inside the while loop**. Everything inside the loop is done each loop cycle. If you only want to have one table in the output, you'll have to open and close the table outside of the loop, like this:

```
    $data= mysql_query("SELECT schInitial FROM matchTable WHERE position='".$facebookID."'")
    or die(mysql_error());
?>
    <center>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tbl_bracket">
<?
    while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {

?>
            <tr>
                <td class="brack_under cell_1"><a href="www.facebook.com"/>team 1.1><?= $row['schInitial']?><a/></td>
                <td class="cell_2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cell_3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cell_4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cell_5">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cell_6">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="brack_under_right_up">team 1.2><?= $row['schInitial']?></</td>
                <td class="brack_right"><!--1.2.1--></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="brack_right"><!--2.1--></td>
                <td class="brack_under"><!--3.1--></td>
                <td><!--here?--></td>
                <td><!--there?--></td>
                <td><!--everywhere?--></td>
            </tr>
 <?
 }
 ?>
        </table>
</center>
```

That will, however, print three rows per loop and therefore per record (but you have references to the table contents in two of them, so I suppose that's what you want?).

Also take care about some not well-formed HTML you have there (e.g. the `>` character in the expression `team 1.1>` / `team 1.2>`. If you want to print the `>` character to the browser, encode it as HTML entity (`&gt;` for this case). You also have a probably superfluous `</` in the first column of the second row (`</</td>`).

Comment: HI nyarlathotep , i get your idea of putting the <table> before the while loop. However i need my record to be different for each td. What i have now is a table with 2 values : "aaa","aaa","aaa". What i want is something like : "abc","def","ghi". I dont want to print three rows per loop , per record . i want to print one row per loop per record. Any ideas? Sorry but i am fairly new to PHP programming :>

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `<table>` tag is within the loop! Place the `<table>` tag outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

place your table tags outside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

you need to echo the HTML part as well in the while loop like

`echo '<table>'`;